# FlatList React Native - full image not showing in each element

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I am trying to use the FlatList in my expo React Native application.  I am able to get the FlatList working but the FULL image is not being displayed for each Item (it appears as though only the top left of the image is being displayed).  Each image is 717x717 in dimension.  Please can someone advise? Perhaps i am having a styling issue? I would like the images not to be of fixed width and height but dynamic in size which is what i tried to achieve below without success.  I have included the link to the images below.

```
const Inspiration = () => {

    const handleSelectedImage = (e) => {
        console.log('image selected', e);
    };
    return (
        <>
            <CreatedImageModal />
            <ModalGeneratingImage />
            <ExamplePrompt />
            <FlatList
                contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                data={EXAMPLES}
                style={styles.list}
                numColumns={2}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                ListHeaderComponent={<Prompt />}

                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Image
                        resizeMode={'contain'}
                        onPress={() => handleSelectedImage(item)}
                        transition={true}
                        source={item.path}
                        containerStyle={styles.item}
                        PlaceholderContent={<ActivityIndicator />}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    list: {
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#000',

    },
    item: {
        aspectRatio: 1,
        width: '100%',
        flex: 1,
    },
});


const EXAMPLES = [
    {
        id: '1',
        path: require('../assets/img-1_small.png'),
        prompt: 'A synthwave style sunset above the reflecting water of the sea, digital art'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        path: require('../assets/img-2_small.png'),
        prompt: 'A van Gogh style painting of an American football player'
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        path: require('../assets/img-3_small.png'),
        prompt: '3D render of a cute tropical fish in an aquarium on a dark blue background, digital art'
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        path: require('../assets/img-4_small.png'),
        prompt: 'A cartoon of a cat catching a mouse'
    },
    {
        id: '5',
        path: require('../assets/img-5_small.png'),
        prompt: 'A comic book cover of a superhero wearing headphones'
    },
    {
        id: '6',
        path: require('../assets/img-6_small.png'),
        prompt: 'A hand-drawn sailboat circled by birds on the sea at sunrise'
    },
    {
        id: '7',
        path: require('../assets/img-7_small.png'),
        prompt: 'An expressive oil painting of a basketball player dunking, depicted as an explosion of a nebula'
    },
    {
        id: '8',
        path: require('../assets/img-8_small.png'),
        prompt: 'A hand drawn sketch of a Porsche 911'
    },
];

export default Inspiration;
```

This is the link to the images i am trying to display [Examples](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dHSRY_dqUOtJ-hHejwn5EtOyEDY30sk_?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Please follow this doc to fix this. https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode

Answer (score 0):

You can add resizeMode in Image Component.

```
<Image
   source={item.path}
   resizeMode={'contain'}
   // Other Props remain same
 />
```

Hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: i have tried this but the results are still like the above. it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

solved your problem
check this Expo snack Link
[Expo Link](https://snack.expo.dev/@muhammadabdullahrishi/gather-data)

Comment: i need the height and width to be the same (<Image />) and dynamic. your example fixes this to 70 so its not what i require

Comment: check now I implement your image style in my code 
https://snack.expo.dev/@muhammadabdullahrishi/gather-data

Comment: I am afraid your solution still only displays a part of each image.  I have updated my question by posting the 8 images that i am trying to display. see link above.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `stretch` property

```
const Inspiration = () => {

    const handleSelectedImage = (e) => {
        console.log('image selected', e);
    };
    return (
        <>
            <CreatedImageModal />
            <ModalGeneratingImage />
            <ExamplePrompt />
            <FlatList
                contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                data={EXAMPLES}
                style={styles.list}
                numColumns={2}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                ListHeaderComponent={<Prompt />}

                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Image
                        resizeMode={'stretch'}
                        onPress={() => handleSelectedImage(item)}
                        transition={true}
                        source={item.path}
                        containerStyle={styles.item}
                        PlaceholderContent={<ActivityIndicator />}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    list: {
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#000',

    },
    item: {
        aspectRatio: 1,
        width: '100%',
        flex: 1,
        height: 400

    },
});
```

you add the Height and Width preferences to your image

you can try my way. hope it can help you